# Add the people automatically to the facebook page

Tags: facebook

I have a fan page at Facebook. 
And I am wanted fans in it but i did not get lot of fans. 
I need some one help that create the steps that will automatically add the peoples to my Facebook fan page.

How can I do it ?

Comment: may i ask about the url of your page?

Comment: probably some spam page? ;) - either way what tobi said is correct. produce good content and the people who are interested in it will like your page. that´s how it works.

Comment: that´s not a facebook page url

Answer (score 0):

No, this is neither possible nor allowed.